# Is it possible to use javascript as a scripting language in Elasticsearch 7.x?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I found some articles and references for Elasticsearch supporting javascript as a scripting language before 2.0, and a lib that was apparently deprecated above 2.0 (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-lang-javascript), but can't find any update on how to use javascript in the [current docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html), or if the support has been removed.

Is it still possible to use javascript or has it been removed as a supported scripting language?

Comment: If you take the effort to downvite this question, you can just as well leave a comment why, so I can improve it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **not available** in plain script [Available scripting languages](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html)

But can be used with Filebeat for example with [Script Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/processor-script.html)